# How to install exe from my project?

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-deployment

I have created a window form application, which needs an external application(Scanner application) support. Hence I need to install that external application exe before installing my setup.exe (or) .msi from a single exe
Please say some way to implement it.

How to embed the external exe into my setup and to proceed with it?
Thanks, Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just use an installer software to create an installation routine that allows to installer other software as a requirement. It's not exactly .NET related.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

It's not the most difficult task in the world, but it will take some time to see which one fits your needs and to get used to working with it, so don't expect it to be download plus 10 minutes.

Is it software for a special audience like a customer or are you going to distribute in on the internet? You may consider, that the scanner software could not allow you do include it into a software package.